# BSOD with Bug Check 0x139 in RemoveEntryList

Tags: windows, serial-port, device-driver, bsod, wdm

We have developed a WDM serial port driver which is based on (WinDDK 6) native serial COM port driver.

But our customer has a application triggering BSOD when using our driver.

This application calls **IRP_MJ_READ** continuously when the button on the program is turned on, and BSOD happened when program is being closed without turning off the button.

We have debugged with WinDBG and found the root cause is `RemoveEntryList` and the Bug check code tells us we have called `RemoveEntryList` twice. See [Bug check 0x139](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check---bug-check-0x139-kernel-security-check-failure).

After analyzing, we can't see differences for the codes between our driver and WinDDK, but native COM1 does not trigger BSOD when runing this application.

The related codes are as followings:

When the program is being closed, the system call `SerialKillAllReadsOrWrites` to kill the pending IRPs in the ReadQueue.

```
VOID
SerialKillAllReadsOrWrites(
    IN PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject,
    IN PLIST_ENTRY QueueToClean,
    IN PIRP *CurrentOpIrp
    )
{

    KIRQL cancelIrql;
    PDRIVER_CANCEL cancelRoutine;

    IoAcquireCancelSpinLock(&cancelIrql);

    //
    // Clean the list from back to front.
    //
    while (!IsListEmpty(QueueToClean)) {

        PIRP currentLastIrp = CONTAINING_RECORD(
                                  QueueToClean->Blink,
                                  IRP,
                                  Tail.Overlay.ListEntry
                                  );

        RemoveEntryList(QueueToClean->Blink);

        cancelRoutine = currentLastIrp->CancelRoutine;
        currentLastIrp->CancelIrql = cancelIrql;
        currentLastIrp->CancelRoutine = NULL;
        currentLastIrp->Cancel = TRUE;

        cancelRoutine(
            DeviceObject,
            currentLastIrp
            );               // <- call SerialCancelQueued()

        IoAcquireCancelSpinLock(&cancelIrql);

    }

    .
    .
    .
}
VOID
SerialCancelQueued(
    PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject,
    PIRP Irp
    )
{

    PSERIAL_DEVICE_EXTENSION extension = DeviceObject->DeviceExtension;
    PIO_STACK_LOCATION irpSp = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp);

    SERIAL_LOCKED_PAGED_CODE();

    Irp->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_CANCELLED;
    Irp->IoStatus.Information = 0;
    RemoveEntryList(&Irp->Tail.Overlay.ListEntry); // <- BSOD happened here!
    .
    .
    .
}
```

We found the first call of `RemoveEntryList` in `SerialKillAllReadsOrWrites` and the second call in `SerialCancelQueued` are going to remove the same entry.

And we have tested that if we mark the first `RemoveEntryList`, it passed, no longer BSOD.

But why native COM doesn't trigger BSOD even for calling `RemoveEntryList` twice to remove the same entry?

Could someone help me to understand why? Thanks.

Comment: you not need call `RemoveEntryList` from `SerialKillAllReadsOrWrites` because you call this from you `CancelRoutine` . of course you can and call `InitializeListHead` after `RemoveEntryList` - in this case it will be safe call it twice, but more correct not call it from `SerialKillAllReadsOrWrites` (when system itself cancel your irp - it also not (an can not) remove your irp from your `QueueToClean`) and you really call `IoAcquireCancelSpinLock(&cancelIrql)` in loop ?

Comment: Yeah, I really call `IoAcquireCancelSpinLock(&cancelIrql)`. I think it is okay because there is a `IoReleaseCancelSpinLock` in the end of `SerialCancelQueued`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found `RemoveEntryList` in WDK8.1 is different in WDK6.
If I build driver by WDK6, Windows will not trigger BSOD when we call `RemoveEntryList` twice.
However, if driver is built by WDK8.1, Windows will trigger BSOD when we call `RemoveEntryList` twice.
So, maybe the original codes in `SerialKillAllReadsOrWrites` should be modified to avoid calling `RemoveEntryList` twice if we want to build driver by WDK8.1.

```
// WDK6:
FORCEINLINE
BOOLEAN
RemoveEntryList(
    _In_ PLIST_ENTRY Entry
    )

{

    PLIST_ENTRY Blink;
    PLIST_ENTRY Flink;

    Flink = Entry->Flink;
    Blink = Entry->Blink;
    Blink->Flink = Flink;
    Flink->Blink = Blink;
    return (BOOLEAN)(Flink == Blink);
}

// WDK 8.1
FORCEINLINE
BOOLEAN
RemoveEntryList(
    _In_ PLIST_ENTRY Entry
    )

{

    PLIST_ENTRY PrevEntry;
    PLIST_ENTRY NextEntry;

    NextEntry = Entry->Flink;
    PrevEntry = Entry->Blink;
    if ((NextEntry->Blink != Entry) || (PrevEntry->Flink != Entry)) {
        FatalListEntryError((PVOID)PrevEntry,
                            (PVOID)Entry,
                            (PVOID)NextEntry);
    }

    PrevEntry->Flink = NextEntry;
    NextEntry->Blink = PrevEntry;
    return (BOOLEAN)(PrevEntry == NextEntry);
}
```